# Network size limitations of `netlm` and `netlogit` from R's SNA package

Tags: r, regression, social-network

I am trying to run `netlogit` on a network of about 60,000 nodes, and I would like to know if the SNA package's functions are designed to support such large operations. I know, for instance, that with RSiena we are not supposed to go further than a few hundred nodes for the algorithms to converge in a reasonable time. But is this the case with SNA's regression models as well?

My initial experience is negative: When I run the commands on my network, the R process expands in memory until it fills both the live memory and the virtual memory and then it crashes (even with one repetition). Is this a matter throwing more resource at R, and is there a good way to calculate how much? Or are the current MRQAP algorithms simply not adapted to such networks? Any resources that can help determine the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response from Carter Butts:

> At present, those functions make heavy use of adjacency representations for the underlying data, and hence do not scale to graphs with more than ~40,000 or so nodes (give or take) - getting around this limit would require a very different implementation.  (Generating sufficiently high quality random permutation vectors might also become a problem as N becomes large, since this is a known challenge for pseudorandom number generators.  However, I am not aware of anyone who has closely examined the issue in this context, so the impact on real-world performance is hard to assess.)  A sparse-data MRQAP implementation for very large graphs could certainly be written, but to make it practical one would need to use an ergm-like term system to calculate covariate values on the fly (since you don't want to store all N^2 values) and whatnot.  Doable, but I don't know if anyone has done it.

Answer (score 3):

`netlogit()` and `rmperm()` (which is used for `netlogit`'s QAP tests) represent networks with matrices. Representing relatively large networks with matrices will use considerable memory. Not related to memory usage, but the underlying code for `netlogit()` and `rmperm()` use for loops within R, which can be slow.

Comment: I gave it even 50GBs of RAM and it still crashed. See Carter's response below.